# How does JavaFx's setOnAction method work under the hood?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

In my object oriented programming class, our recent topic has been event-driven programming through JavaFX. The concepts have been relatively interesting, though at times quite confusing to me. One thing that I have struggled quite greatly to understand is the workings of the `setOnAction()` method.

As my instructor said, this method takes in an object of a class that has a handle method, and calls that handle method whenever an event is fired.

For example in our `start` method:

```
class MyHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.out.println("Handled");
        }
    }

Button button = new Button();
button.setOnAction(new MyHandler());
```

However, I'm unable to understand how this works under the hood. How exactly does the `setOnAction` method "know" to call the handle method of the `MyHandler` object? Is it possible to implement my own version of a `setOnAction`, in which I call a specifically named method of any passed in object?

And what if we don't implement a handle method at all, but instead say, a `fakeHandle` method, like this.

```
class MyHandler {
        public void fakeHandle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.out.println("Handled");
        }
    }

Button button = new Button();
button.setOnAction(new MyHandler());
```

Would our code still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As my instructor said, this method takes in an object of a class that has a handle method, and calls that handle method whenever an event is fired.

I suspect there's a slight misunderstanding or a poor choice of words happening here. You cannot pass any arbitrary object whose class defines a `handle(ActionEvent)` method to the `setOnAction` method. The `setOnAction` method is defined to accept an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` implementation, and it's *that interface* that defines the `handle` method.

This is exactly what interfaces are for. They define a contract that all implementations must follow. It doesn't matter what object you pass to `setOnAction` so long as its class implements `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. And that's how JavaFX knows about the `handle` method, because it knows about the `EventHandler` interface.

Your second code example won't compile because `myHandler` doesn't implement `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. But even if it did your `fakeHandle` method would not be invoked (by JavaFX code) because JavaFX is not aware of it.

---

Explaining exactly how the entire event-handling process works under-the-hood in JavaFX is an in-depth process. If you really want to understand this then I suggest reading the code—[JavaFX is open source](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx). However, if you only want to understand event-handling from a user's perspective (i.e. an API level) then [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm#JFXED117) should help.

Comment: Ah, I see! So there's essentially an instanceOf check going on, where we check to make sure whether the passed in object actually implements ```EventHandler<ActionEvent>``` right?

Comment: No `instanceof` required. The method's signature is `public final void setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>)`. The static type checking done by the compiler ensures that the argument implements `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. Then internally JavaFX keeps a reference to the instance as an `EventHandler`. This is known as "programming to an interface" and is no different than doing something like `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Ah okay, so essentially we are just making a static reference to the object as an interface, which is then, in turn, checked by the compiler. And since the ```EventHandler``` forces an implementation of handle to exist, the ```setOnAction``` guy knows to call handle. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you basically got the idea. But note the `setOnAction` method does not call `handle`. All it does is register the `EventHandler` with JavaFX's event-handling mechanism. It's that mechanism that calls `handle` when appropriate.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch for the help. I can't upvote your answer due to low rep, but once I have the right amount, I'll be sure to come back and upvote.